# How to draw plus sign (+) into n*n numpy zero array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How we can replace elements of a NumPy array of size (n*n) if we have np.zeros array and need to replace it with 1's so that shape looks like '+' such that 1's must be present at the middle row and column.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.zeros(5*5).reshape(5,5)
x[2:3,2:3] = 1
```

### output:

```
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
```

### but expected is:

```
   [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
   [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Those slices aren't quite right. Use `x=np.zeros((5,5)); x[2,1:4]=1; x[1:4,2]=1`

Comment: Your question title is way too general

Answer (score 3):

You can do your task the following way:

```
n = x.shape[0] // 2
x[n, n-1:n+2] = 1
x[n-1:n+2, n] = 1
```

I created the array passing *dtype='int'* and got:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

(integers).

Or if you want to have *1* in **all** elements of the middle column and row,
run:

```
x[n, :] = 1
x[:, n] = 1
```

This time you will get:

```
array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]])
```

## Edit following the comment about even-sized array

In case of an even-sized array, you can use just the same code,
but this time the "cross" is not exactly in the middle.

E.g. if the array is `6 * 6`, the result is:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]])
```

Or, if you accept the cross of "double" width (**2** middle rows and columns),
you can run:

```
n = x.shape[0] // 2
x[n-1:n, :] = 1
x[:, n-1:n] = 1
```

This time the result will be:

```
array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]])
```

If you don't know in advance the shape of the array, you must check
whether the number of rows is even or odd and then run the suitable
version of my code (both versions in *if / else* block).

Comment: What about an even-sized array ;)